# Tenses to describe a picture

Tags: tense, present-simple

I know that the Present Continuous can be used to describe a picture. What about the Present Simple and other tenses?

If the Present Simple is possible what makes us use it instead of the Present Continuous?

For example. There is a picture of  CopperKettle (a member of this forum) typing a message on his/her computer.

Is it OK to say:

1. In the picture CopperKettle is **typing** a message
   or
2. In the picture CopperKettle **types** a message.

Comment: Example sentence please.

Comment: One desribes a routine, the other one a temporary action.

Answer (score 4):

You can describe a picture using the simple present if you like.

Printed captions under pictures or photos are often in the simple present to give a sense of immediacy to wherever is depicted. This is also true of newspaper headlines: *Titanic sinks!*

This is similar to the following uses of the simple present:

1 Giving a play-by-play description of a football match
*Smith passes the ball to Jones, Jones heads it to Johnson, Johnson stops it, he kicks and scores!*

2 Giving a demonstration, as on a cooking show
*I take the chicken and dip it into the special sauce, then I place it in the cooking pan. I place the pan in the oven and let it cook for twenty minutes. While I wait, I chop some tomatoes...*

3 Joke telling:
*The past, present, and future **walk** into a bar. It was tense.* (Joke from Fallout 4.) The joke apparently works better with the past simple in the second clause, if it works at all.

4 Story telling
*There's this guy, you see. And he goes into the forest looking for his good pair of shoes, which he's been missing for a week. He comes upon this bear. Then he notices he's in between a mama bear and her bear cubs. He decides to...*

5 Historical present
*In 1492 Columbus comes upon a land he thinks is the East Indies. He sends out a landing party and the party meets the local natives, who don't look that much like Indians, yet the crew and their commander refer to them by this name.*

6 Chapter titles or descriptions in an older book such as by Charles Dickens:
*I I wake up to a knock at the door.

II The Earl comes home.

III We travel to meet Scrooger*

You can use whatever tense is appropriate to describe the photo.

*This was Bobby Joe when he was first learning to walk*

But since the photo still shows the same scene now, in the present, you can refer to it with the present simple. This is like pointing to a picture and telling us what it depicts:

*This is Bobby Joe when he is (or was) first learning to walk.*